# What is the namespace of "AdalDistributedTokenCache"

Tags: c#, azure-active-directory, openid-connect

I am following this guide [AzureAdal](https://joonasw.net/view/aspnet-core-2-azure-ad-authentication) to connect to the AzureAD. In the guide  the class "AdalDistributedTokenCache" is used. But Visual Studio can't find the namespace and I get zero search results for NuGet packages or any other type of searches.

Does anybody know how to reach this class?

Comment: May be you could find it in this [link](https://github.com/juunas11/aspnetcore2aadauth/blob/master/Core2AadAuth/Services/AdalDistributedTokenCache.cs).

Comment: I undeleted the question

Comment: Blog post author here, I made that class, it's in my GitHub repo.

Comment: Ok, many thanks for the information an the class.

Comment: @juunas Where did you store the `ClientSecret`?

Comment: In user secrets for development, what you use in production depends on where you deploy the app. You can put it in environment variables, Azure Key Vault, it's kind of up to you :)

Comment: Ok. I thank you for your quick reply!

Comment: I got it to work with the help of you blog and sample code. Thank you once again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could find it in this [link](https://github.com/juunas11/aspnetcore2aadauth/blob/master/Core2AadAuth/Services/AdalDistributedTokenCache.cs).

```
using Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory;
```

Comment: found the nuget for it: `Microsoft.Experimental.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory` thanx for the help!

Comment: @AllramEst Glad to help you.